# Pharmacode in FastReport.net

Tags: c#, report, barcode, fastreport

I have to use a [Pharmacode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacode) for my reports which I've designed in FastReport.Net.

I can't find this barcode in my report designer. Has anyone used this barcode in a FastReport.Net report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pharmacode was added in the 2017.1.6 build.

[image: Pharmacode]